# How to style errors(with good padding) and make error container disappear when form is valid in jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: css, jquery-validate

I'm trying to make beatiful error form for a long period of time, but I'm missing something.
some 
I want to place all my errors usingfrom [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) in some error container, and then hide it, when form is valid.

Of course, I want to make my form look good, so I need to add padding to elements.

If I add padding to error container, I will  get this situation: 
when field was valid, and then turned into valid I will have line, that have width of my container padding. Here is screenshot:

[image]

Here is css :

```
  #messageBox1{
display:none;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;    
width:305px;
background-color: rgb(242, 222, 222);
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
 }
```

HTML in view:

and js code:

```
     $(".login").validate({
    rules: {

        "user[email]":{
            email: true,
            required: true
        },
         'user[password]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            remote: {
             url: url_name.concat("checkpass"),
            type: "get",
            data: {
              email: function() { return $("#user_email").val(); 
              }
            }

          }
        }
    },
    messages: {
    "user[email]": {
    remote: "You entered wrong email",
    required: "Your email is required"
    },
    'user[password]':{
    required: "Password is required",
    minlength: "Your password is too short",
    remote: "Your password is incorrect"
      }
    },
    errorContainer: "#messageBox1",
     errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1",
     wrapper: "li"

 })
```

Is it possible to make this stupif bug go away from my life ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your CSS selector messageBox1Box1 but the message box id is messageBox1? and add one more space at the beginning of the html first line of code, it isn't showing.

Comment: I think, I can add padding if I have one error - using jQuery, but it will be hard I think.

Comment: Honestly looking at that code now the div shouldn't show unless there are errors anyway? even with padding since it's set to display none.

Comment: It is not displaying, when there are no errors - then, when error is adding - it appears and padding is adding.

Comment: Check edit to my answer, it should set the div back to display none on success.

Comment: It was SO simple, but how much time I spent on this! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the padding to the li elements themselves rather than the box.

```
#messageBox1 li{padding: 5px 0;}
#messageBox1 li:first-child{padding: 10px 0 0 0;}
#messageBox1 li:last-child{padding: 0 0 10px 0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Vn69J/

Okay how about adding a success to the validate function, if I am reading you right it happens after an error and then a valid response.

```
rules: {

    "user[email]":{
        email: true,
        required: true
    },
     'user[password]': {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        remote: {
         url: url_name.concat("checkpass"),
        type: "get",
        data: {
          email: function() { return $("#user_email").val(); 
          }
        }

      }
    }
},
messages: {
"user[email]": {
remote: "You entered wrong email",
required: "Your email is required"
},
'user[password]':{
required: "Password is required",
minlength: "Your password is too short",
remote: "Your password is incorrect"
  }
},
errorContainer: "#messageBox1",
 errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1",
 wrapper: "li"

},
success: function() {
 $('#messageBox1').css('display', 'none');
})
```

Comment: Ok, but first and last error will have different paddings, isn't it ?

Comment: See edit, I am not positive how well supported the child selectors are though.

Comment: Try to leave only one li object - you will receive the same.

Comment: Yeah I see that, it takes on the last selector that fits... hmmm

Comment: Well actually, this is a login validation, you should only have one error anyway, the one telling them their login credentials are incorrect. You don't want to say which part is wrong, because that is a bit of a security risk. That doesn't however solve the problem for other types of validation, let me keep fiddling with this.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But I also tell if user enters invalid email format.

Comment: I tested it again ... and it is hiding container when one input is valid, but another - isn't ...